# Authorship for helping collect data for 1 or 2 figures

Tags: publications, authorship

What is the threshold that must be crossed to go from contributor to author? I am freelancing a bit, helping out another group with their experimental design and data processing. While I do not physically do anything, the graduate student I am working with implements my suggestions. I provide the program to analyze and extract the pertinent data. I am assuming I would be responsible for some of the writing in explaining what is going on.

Obviously, I should ask before going too far down the road on this but I figured I would throw this question to the exchange to see if I am wasting my breath. I am not looking for co, 1st or anything, just wondering if I can eek out a CV entry.

Answer (score 3):

If you're actually writing part of the paper, and actually doing analysis and interpreting the results of the data, then yes you can ask. If it's providing suggestions "try this method/program/analysis" and letting them do the rest, then I'd say being mentioned in the acknowledgements sounds like enough credit.

Comment: Experimental design is also an intellectual contribution. Again, if OP is just looking over *their* DoE and OKing it, that's for an acknowledgment. If OP is adding more substantially, coauthorship is indicated.